# iOS: audio recording metering without creating a file

Tags: ios, audio, avcapturesession, avaudiorecorder

I would like to meter my audio input level without creating a file.
I've read all the various post and found these approaches:

1. Use `AVAudioRecorder` and write to /dev/null (which indeed is a good idea but doesn't work for me on iOS 8/9)
2. Use `AVCaptureSession` which worked for me, but I don't know which implications this might have on AppStore submission *(first question)*. Another down side seemed that it constantly will use around 10% of CPU on an iPad2 *(second question)*.

This is my code, inspired by similar SO posts:

```
func startCapture() {
    if let device : AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio){

        do {
            self.session = AVCaptureSession()
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            let audioInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)
            device.unlockForConfiguration()

            if(self.session.canAddInput(audioInput)){
                self.session.addInput(audioInput)
                print("added input")
            }


            let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()

            audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0))

            if(self.session.canAddOutput(audioOutput)){
                self.session.addOutput(audioOutput)
                print("added output")
            }


            //supposed to start session not on UI queue coz it takes a while
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                print("starting captureSession")
                self.session.startRunning()
            }

        } catch {

        }
    }
}

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, let didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    var buffer: CMBlockBuffer? = nil

    // Needs to be initialized somehow, even if we take only the address
    var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(mNumberBuffers: 1,
                                          mBuffers: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 1, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil))

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
        sampleBuffer,
        nil,
        &audioBufferList,
        sizeof(audioBufferList.dynamicType),
        nil,
        nil,
        UInt32(kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment),
        &buffer
    )

    let abl = UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer(&audioBufferList)

    for buffer in abl {
        let samples = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int16>(start: UnsafeMutablePointer(buffer.mData),
                                                        count: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize)/sizeof(Int16))

        var sum:Int64 = 0

        for sample in samples {
            let s = Int64(sample)
            sum = (sum + s*s)
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            print( String(sqrt(Float(sum/Int64(samples.count)))))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: 1. Why does it use 10% of CPU vs. AVAudioRecorder using 3%?
2. Might using AVCaptureSession have any issues with AppStore submission (as I haven't used it before)?